# Giving a value to Provider in guice

Tags: java, guice, provider

I have the following Provider:

```
class MyProvider implements Provider<T> {
  private final ClassX objectX;
  private String name;

  @Inject
  public MyProvider(ClassX objectX) {
    this.objectX = objectX
  }

  T get() {
    // uses name and objectX to provide an object of T
  }
}
```

my bindings look like this:

```
List<String> names;
for (String name : names) {
  bind(T.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(name))
    .toProvider(MyProvider.class)  // somehow set name in Provider
}
```

The constructor argument to provider is available from some other module (and injector is created from this and that other module). I am not able to figure out how to give that name to the provider. The ideal way would be to have that as a constructor argument as well, as set its value in the binding. Any idea how something like that can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

I did this finally

```
class MyProvider implements Provider<T> {
  private ClassX objectX;
  private final String name;


  public MyProvider(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Inject
  public setClassX(ClassX objectX) {
    this.objectX = objectX
  }

  T get() {
    // uses name and objectX to provide an object of T
  }
}
```

And the bindings:

```
List<String> names;
for (String name : names) {
  MyProvider provider = new MyProvider(name);
  requestInjection(provider);
  bind(T.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(name))
    .toProvider(provider)  // somehow set name in Provider
}
```

The `requestInjection()` method is the key, which basically injects object, from within the same injector, to methods annotated with `@Inject`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. Guice bindings should always be specific; each binding key, which identifies what Guice has to inject at certain injection point, consists of a type and an a possible annotation: `(Type, Optional<Annotation>) -> Implementation`, and you cannot omit the type here, which is what you are really trying to achieve.

However, Guice is able to bind wildcard types, i.e. it is possible to bind, say, `List<?>` to some provider (using `TypeLiteral`). So, I imagine, you should be able to create a class, say `Cell<T>`, which wraps an object of type `T`, and create a binding for `Cell<?>`. However, then you should be able to inject only `Cell<?>`, not a concrete type like `Cell<String>`. I don't know for sure, and maybe Guice allows such magic, but it is not very likely.

BTW, you can pass any arguments to provider constructor and supply its managed dependencies via fields or methods. Then you can bind to the instance of that provider:

```
bind(Smth.class).toProvider(new SmthProvider("whatever"));
```

Comment: If managed dependencies are supplied by fields or methods, those objects will not be injected when you do a new SmthProvider("whatever");

Comment: Hmm, I thought it would work. Well, it's impossible to know everything :)

Comment: @Aman Actually, `toProvider()` automatically performs member (field and setter) injection on its argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically look up objects in a provider.  However you have to know ahead of time all of the names you may want.  This will work:

```
class MyProvider implements Provider<T> {
  private final Class<T> objectX;
  private final String name;

  @Inject
  public MyProvider(Class<T> objectX, String name) {
    this.objectX = objectX
    this.name = name;
  }

  public T get() {
    // uses name and objectX to provide an object of T
  }
```

}

and then the bindings - you need one provider instance per name:

```
List<String> names = ...;
for (String name : names) {
  bind(SpecificType.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(name))
    .toProvider(new MyProvider<SpecificType>(SpecificType.class, name));
}
```

If you are caching results or anything like that you may need some synchronization.